# how replace whitespaces in string with dash - php

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace any occurrence of whitespaces with single dash , if there was more than one whitespace then it should be replaced with one dash only

for example :

```
$string = "testing string"              //should be "testing-string"
$string = "testing      string"         //should be "testing-string"
$string = "testing\t\t\n\n  string"     //should be "testing-string"
```

I had tried this :

```
$string = "this is   testing  string\n\n\nxyz\t\t\tabc";
echo preg_replace('![\s+|\t+|\n+]!', "-" , $string);
```

but the problem it replace every single whitespace with single dash

Comment: `preg_replace('~\s+~', "-" , $string);` should work fine as `\s` matches all whitespaces. Inside `[...]` `+` matches a literal `+`

Answer (score 2):

You have written the pattern wrong, what you really need is this `[\s]+`

Check this out:

```
$string = "this is   testing  string\n\n\nxyz\t\t\tabc";
echo preg_replace('![\s]+!', "-" , $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/(\s|\t|\n)+/ui', "-" , $string);
```

Comment: `\t` and `\n` are included in `\s` and `/ui` flags are useless here.